# Full Control admins can't delete sites across site collection because of record hold

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-server, publishing-site

It's been brought to my attention that Full Control site admins on one of my SharePoint Server 2013 site collections are unable to delete their own sub-sites. The error that presents when they attempt to do so is:

> Sorry, something went wrong  This site cannot be deleted because there
>   might be items which are either on hold or declared as records in this
>   site. Only a Site Collection Administrator or an eDiscovery Manager
>   can delete sites with held content or records.

As administrator I can successfully delete the subsites, but this is not a function I want to be in the middle of for them. I tested other collections in our farm and they do not have this problem - it's just this one. And there are multiple teams with secured sites in this collection so making everyone a site collection admin is not an option.

I've done my best to troubleshoot this before crowdsourcing help but I've hit a wall and hoping someone might have some ideas for where I can look next. Things I've already tried:

- Mirroring full control permissions with my test account, which also gets the error
- Creating a new blank publishing site from scratch at the site collection root, which my test account still gets the error on
- Deleting individual lists and libraries off affected sites with test account -- the only ones left are the default Documents, Images, Pages, Workflow Tasks created with blank publishing site which can't be removed by end user. Still can't delete the site.
- Checked Information Management Policy Settings on every list/library and none list any defined.
- I've seen some posts which suggest this could be from a custom content or column type at the site collection level, or perhaps a feature, but I've flipped through there and can't find anything that sticks out. We don't have a lot of customizations going on, but it's possible there's some remnant from before my time (5+ years ago) that's still left over and nobody but me has tried to delete any sites in all that time.

Which leads me to here, stuck and asking all of you for ideas. I pulled the log from the correlation ID and nothing appears relevant, but in case you notice something I missed I've included that below as well. Please halp!

```
Timestamp               Process                                     TID     Area                            Category                        EventID Level       Message     Correlation
02/15/2019 14:00:28.95  w3wp.exe (SP13WEB2:0x068C)                  0x3660  SharePoint Foundation           Logging Correlation Data        xmnv    Medium  Name=Request (POST:https://SITE/COLLECTION/TEST/_layouts/15/deleteweb.aspx) 9b55c09e-f501-1059-492f-40de48580415
02/15/2019 14:00:28.95  w3wp.exe (SP13WEB2:0x068C)                  0x3660  SharePoint Foundation           Authentication Authorization    agb9s   Medium  Non-OAuth request. IsAuthenticated=True, UserIdentityName=0#.w|DOMAIN\qauser5, ClaimsCount=29   9b55c09e-f501-1059-492f-40de48580415
02/15/2019 14:00:28.95  w3wp.exe (SP13WEB2:0x068C)                  0x3660  SharePoint Foundation           Logging Correlation Data        xmnv    Medium  Site=/collab    9b55c09e-f501-1059-492f-40de48580415
02/15/2019 14:00:28.99  w3wp.exe (SP13WEB2:0x068C)                  0x3660  SharePoint Foundation           Files                           ak8dj   High    UserAgent not available, file operations may not be optimized.    at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPFileStreamManager.get_UserAgent()     at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPFileStreamManager.CreateCobaltStreamContainer(SPFileStreamStore spfs, ILockBytes ilb, Boolean copyOnFirstWrite, Boolean disposeIlb)     at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPFileStreamManager.SetInputLockBytes(SPFileInfo& fileInfo, SqlSession session, PrefetchResult prefetchResult)     at Microsoft.SharePoint.CoordinatedStreamBuffer.SPCoordinatedStreamBufferFactory.CreateFromDocumentRowset(Guid databaseId, SqlSession session, SPFileStreamManager spfstm, Object[] metadataRow, SPRowset contentRowset, SPDocumentBindRequest& dbreq, SPDocumentBindResults& dbres)     at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPSqlClient.GetDocumentContentRow(Int32 rowOrd, Object ospFileSt... 9b55c09e-f501-1059-492f-40de48580415
02/15/2019 14:00:28.99* w3wp.exe (SP13WEB2:0x068C)                  0x3660  SharePoint Foundation           Files                           ak8dj   High    ...mMgr, SPDocumentBindRequest& dbreq, SPDocumentBindResults& dbres)     at Microsoft.SharePoint.Library.SPRequestInternalClass.GetFileAndMetaInfo(String bstrUrl, Byte bPageView, Byte bPageMode, Byte bGetBuildDependencySet, String bstrCurrentFolderUrl, Int32 iRequestVersion, Byte bMainFileRequest, Boolean& pbCanCustomizePages, Boolean& pbCanPersonalizeWebParts, Boolean& pbCanAddDeleteWebParts, Boolean& pbGhostedDocument, Boolean& pbDefaultToPersonal, Boolean& pbIsWebWelcomePage, String& pbstrSiteRoot, Guid& pgSiteId, UInt32& pdwVersion, String& pbstrTimeLastModified, String& pbstrContent, UInt32& pdwPartCount, Object& pvarMetaData, Object& pvarMultipleMeetingDoclibRootFolders, String& pbstrRedirectUrl, Boolean& pbObjectIsList, Guid& pgListId, UInt32& pdwItemId, Int64& pllListFlags, Boolean& p...  9b55c09e-f501-1059-492f-40de48580415
02/15/2019 14:00:28.99* w3wp.exe (SP13WEB2:0x068C)                  0x3660  SharePoint Foundation           Files                           ak8dj   High    ...bAccessDenied, Guid& pgDocid, Byte& piLevel, UInt64& ppermMask, Object& pvarBuildDependencySet, UInt32& pdwNumBuildDependencies, Object& pvarBuildDependencies, String& pbstrFolderUrl, String& pbstrContentTypeOrder, Guid& pgDocScopeId)     at Microsoft.SharePoint.Library.SPRequestInternalClass.GetFileAndMetaInfo(String bstrUrl, Byte bPageView, Byte bPageMode, Byte bGetBuildDependencySet, String bstrCurrentFolderUrl, Int32 iRequestVersion, Byte bMainFileRequest, Boolean& pbCanCustomizePages, Boolean& pbCanPersonalizeWebParts, Boolean& pbCanAddDeleteWebParts, Boolean& pbGhostedDocument, Boolean& pbDefaultToPersonal, Boolean& pbIsWebWelcomePage, String& pbstrSiteRoot, Guid& pgSiteId, UInt32& pdwVersion, String& pbstrTimeLastModified, String& pbstrContent, UInt32& pdwPartCount, Object& pvarMeta...  9b55c09e-f501-1059-492f-40de48580415
02/15/2019 14:00:28.99* w3wp.exe (SP13WEB2:0x068C)                  0x3660  SharePoint Foundation           Files                           ak8dj   High    ...Data, Object& pvarMultipleMeetingDoclibRootFolders, String& pbstrRedirectUrl, Boolean& pbObjectIsList, Guid& pgListId, UInt32& pdwItemId, Int64& pllListFlags, Boolean& pbAccessDenied, Guid& pgDocid, Byte& piLevel, UInt64& ppermMask, Object& pvarBuildDependencySet, UInt32& pdwNumBuildDependencies, Object& pvarBuildDependencies, String& pbstrFolderUrl, String& pbstrContentTypeOrder, Guid& pgDocScopeId)     at Microsoft.SharePoint.Library.SPRequest.GetFileAndMetaInfo(String bstrUrl, Byte bPageView, Byte bPageMode, Byte bGetBuildDependencySet, String bstrCurrentFolderUrl, Int32 iRequestVersion, Byte bMainFileRequest, Boolean& pbCanCustomizePages, Boolean& pbCanPersonalizeWebParts, Boolean& pbCanAddDeleteWebParts, Boolean& pbGhostedDocument, Boolean& pbDefaultToPersonal, Boolean& pbIsWebWelcome...  9b55c09e-f501-1059-492f-40de48580415
02/15/2019 14:00:28.99* w3wp.exe (SP13WEB2:0x068C)                  0x3660  SharePoint Foundation           Files                           ak8dj   High    ...Page, String& pbstrSiteRoot, Guid& pgSiteId, UInt32& pdwVersion, String& pbstrTimeLastModified, String& pbstrContent, UInt32& pdwPartCount, Object& pvarMetaData, Object& pvarMultipleMeetingDoclibRootFolders, String& pbstrRedirectUrl, Boolean& pbObjectIsList, Guid& pgListId, UInt32& pdwItemId, Int64& pllListFlags, Boolean& pbAccessDenied, Guid& pgDocid, Byte& piLevel, UInt64& ppermMask, Object& pvarBuildDependencySet, UInt32& pdwNumBuildDependencies, Object& pvarBuildDependencies, String& pbstrFolderUrl, String& pbstrContentTypeOrder, Guid& pgDocScopeId)     at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPWeb.GetWebPartPageContent(Uri pageUrl, Int32 pageVersion, PageView requestedView, HttpContext context, Boolean forRender, Boolean includeHidden, Boolean mainFileRequest, Boolean fetchDependencyInformation, Bool...  9b55c09e-f501-1059-492f-40de48580415
02/15/2019 14:00:28.99* w3wp.exe (SP13WEB2:0x068C)                  0x3660  SharePoint Foundation           Files                           ak8dj   High    ...ean& ghostedPage, String& siteRoot, Guid& siteId, Int64& bytes, Guid& docId, UInt32& docVersion, String& timeLastModified, Byte& level, Object& buildDependencySetData, UInt32& dependencyCount, Object& buildDependencies, SPWebPartCollectionInitialState& initialState, Object& oMultipleMeetingDoclibRootFolders, String& redirectUrl, Boolean& ObjectIsList, Guid& listId)     at Microsoft.SharePoint.ApplicationRuntime.SPRequestModuleData.FetchWebPartPageInformationForInit(HttpContext context, SPWeb spweb, Boolean mainFileRequest, String path, Boolean impersonate, Boolean& isAppWeb, Boolean& fGhostedPage, Guid& docId, UInt32& docVersion, String& timeLastModified, SPFileLevel& spLevel, String& masterPageUrl, String& customMasterPageUrl, String& webUrl, String& siteUrl, Guid& siteId, Object& buildDe...  9b55c09e-f501-1059-492f-40de48580415
02/15/2019 14:00:28.99* w3wp.exe (SP13WEB2:0x068C)                  0x3660  SharePoint Foundation           Files                           ak8dj   High    ...pendencySetData, SPWebPartCollectionInitialState& initialState, String& siteRoot, String& redirectUrl, Object& oMultipleMeetingDoclibRootFolders, Boolean& objectIsList, Guid& listId, Int64& bytes)     at Microsoft.SharePoint.ApplicationRuntime.SPRequestModuleData.FetchWebPartPageInformation(HttpContext context, String path, Boolean impersonate, Boolean& isAppWeb, Boolean& fGhostedPage, Guid& docId, UInt32& docVersion, String& timeLastModified, SPFileLevel& level, String& masterpageUrl, String& customMasterPageUrl, String& webUrl, String& siteUrl, Guid& siteId, Object& buildDependencySetData)     at Microsoft.SharePoint.ApplicationRuntime.SPRequestModuleData.GetWebPartPageData(HttpContext context, String path, Boolean throwIfFileNotFound)     at Microsoft.SharePoint.ApplicationRuntime.SPVir...  9b55c09e-f501-1059-492f-40de48580415
02/15/2019 14:00:28.99* w3wp.exe (SP13WEB2:0x068C)                  0x3660  SharePoint Foundation           Files                           ak8dj   High    ...tualFile.GetVirtualPathProviderCacheKey(String virtualPath)     at Microsoft.SharePoint.ApplicationRuntime.SPVirtualPathProvider.GetCacheKey(String virtualPath)     at System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.GetCacheKeyFromVirtualPath(VirtualPath virtualPath, Boolean& keyFromVPP)     at System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.GetVPathBuildResultFromCacheInternal(VirtualPath virtualPath, Boolean ensureIsUpToDate)     at System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.GetVPathBuildResultInternal(VirtualPath virtualPath, Boolean noBuild, Boolean allowCrossApp, Boolean allowBuildInPrecompile, Boolean throwIfNotFound, Boolean ensureIsUpToDate)     at System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.GetVPathBuildResultWithNoAssert(HttpContext context, VirtualPath virtualPath, Boolean noBuild, Boolean allowCrossApp, Boolean allo...  9b55c09e-f501-1059-492f-40de48580415
02/15/2019 14:00:28.99* w3wp.exe (SP13WEB2:0x068C)                  0x3660  SharePoint Foundation           Files                           ak8dj   High    ...wBuildInPrecompile, Boolean throwIfNotFound, Boolean ensureIsUpToDate)     at System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.GetVPathBuildResult(HttpContext context, VirtualPath virtualPath, Boolean noBuild, Boolean allowCrossApp, Boolean allowBuildInPrecompile, Boolean ensureIsUpToDate)     at System.Web.UI.MasterPage.CreateMaster(TemplateControl owner, HttpContext context, VirtualPath masterPageFile, IDictionary contentTemplateCollection)     at System.Web.UI.Page.get_Master()     at System.Web.UI.Page.ApplyMasterPage()     at System.Web.UI.Page.PerformPreInit()     at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)     at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequest(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) ...  9b55c09e-f501-1059-492f-40de48580415
02/15/2019 14:00:28.99* w3wp.exe (SP13WEB2:0x068C)                  0x3660  SharePoint Foundation           Files                           ak8dj   High    ...    at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequest()     at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)     at System.Web.HttpApplication.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()     at System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStepImpl(IExecutionStep step)     at System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously)     at System.Web.HttpApplication.PipelineStepManager.ResumeSteps(Exception error)     at System.Web.HttpApplication.BeginProcessRequestNotification(HttpContext context, AsyncCallback cb)     at System.Web.HttpRuntime.ProcessRequestNotificationPrivate(IIS7WorkerRequest wr, HttpContext context)     at System.Web.Hosting.PipelineRuntime.ProcessRequestNotificationHelper(IntPtr rootedObjectsPointer, IntPtr nativeR...  9b55c09e-f501-1059-492f-40de48580415
02/15/2019 14:00:28.99* w3wp.exe (SP13WEB2:0x068C)                  0x3660  SharePoint Foundation           Files                           ak8dj   High    ...equestContext, IntPtr moduleData, Int32 flags)     at System.Web.Hosting.PipelineRuntime.ProcessRequestNotification(IntPtr rootedObjectsPointer, IntPtr nativeRequestContext, IntPtr moduleData, Int32 flags)     at System.Web.Hosting.UnsafeIISMethods.MgdIndicateCompletion(IntPtr pHandler, RequestNotificationStatus& notificationStatus)     at System.Web.Hosting.UnsafeIISMethods.MgdIndicateCompletion(IntPtr pHandler, RequestNotificationStatus& notificationStatus)     at System.Web.Hosting.PipelineRuntime.ProcessRequestNotificationHelper(IntPtr rootedObjectsPointer, IntPtr nativeRequestContext, IntPtr moduleData, Int32 flags)     at System.Web.Hosting.PipelineRuntime.ProcessRequestNotification(IntPtr rootedObjectsPointer, IntPtr nativeRequestContext, IntPtr moduleData, Int32 flags)  9b55c09e-f501-1059-492f-40de48580415
02/15/2019 14:00:28.99  w3wp.exe (SP13WEB2:0x068C)                  0x3660  SharePoint Foundation           Files                           aiv4w   Medium  Spent 0 ms to bind 34503 byte file stream   9b55c09e-f501-1059-492f-40de48580415
02/15/2019 14:00:29.00  w3wp.exe (SP13WEB2:0x068C)                  0x3660  SharePoint Foundation           Files                           ahjkm   Medium  Spent 15 ms to send 34503 byte file stream  9b55c09e-f501-1059-492f-40de48580415
02/15/2019 14:00:29.02  w3wp.exe (SP13WEB2:0x068C)                  0x3660  SharePoint Foundation           General                         m7hw    High    Recycling the web at https://SITE/COLLECTION/TEST . 9b55c09e-f501-1059-492f-40de48580415
02/15/2019 14:00:29.24  w3wp.exe (SP13WEB2:0x068C)                  0x3660  SharePoint Foundation           Dev Events                      ajekb   High    [Forced due to logging gap, cached @ 02/15/2019 14:00:29.02, Original Level: Verbose] Invoking EventReceiver - [Id: {0}]    9b55c09e-f501-1059-492f-40de48580415
02/15/2019 14:00:29.24  w3wp.exe (SP13WEB2:0x068C)                  0x3660  SharePoint Foundation           Monitoring                      b4ly    High    Leaving Monitored Scope (Event Receiver (Microsoft.SharePoint.Publishing, Version=15.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c, Microsoft.SharePoint.Publishing.CPVAreaEventReceiver)). Execution Time=215.863744850456   9b55c09e-f501-1059-492f-40de48580415
02/15/2019 14:00:29.25  w3wp.exe (SP13WEB2:0x068C)                  0x3660  Document Management Server      Information Policy Management   4zxi    High    Hold Web Deletion activation event handled. 9b55c09e-f501-1059-492f-40de48580415
02/15/2019 14:00:29.35  w3wp.exe (SP13WEB2:0x068C)                  0x3660  SharePoint Foundation           General                         8kh7    High    This site cannot be deleted because there might be items which are either on hold or declared as records in this site. Only a Site Collection Administrator or an eDiscovery Manager can delete sites with held content or records. 9b55c09e-f501-1059-492f-40de48580415
02/15/2019 14:00:29.35  w3wp.exe (SP13WEB2:0x068C)                  0x3660  SharePoint Foundation           Dev Events                      ajekb   High    [Forced due to logging gap, cached @ 02/15/2019 14:00:29.24, Original Level: Verbose] Invoking EventReceiver - [Id: {0}]    9b55c09e-f501-1059-492f-40de48580415
02/15/2019 14:00:29.35  w3wp.exe (SP13WEB2:0x068C)                  0x3660  SharePoint Foundation           General                         aix9j   High    SPRequest.DeleteWeb: UserPrincipalName=i:0).w|s-1-5-21-1129549822-3088922563-2289938303-112354, AppPrincipalName= ,bstrUrl=https://SITE/COLLECTION/TEST ,bRecycle=True  9b55c09e-f501-1059-492f-40de48580415
02/15/2019 14:00:29.35  w3wp.exe (SP13WEB2:0x068C)                  0x3660  SharePoint Foundation           General                         ai1wu   Medium  System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException: This site cannot be deleted because there might be items which are either on hold or declared as records in this site. Only a Site Collection Administrator or an eDiscovery Manager can delete sites with held content or records., StackTrace:    at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPWeb.Recycle()     at Microsoft.SharePoint.ApplicationPages.DeleteWebPage.<BtnDelete_Click>b__1(SPLongOperation longOperation)     at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPLongOperation.Begin(String leadingHtml, String trailingHtml, BeginOperation beginOperation)     at Microsoft.SharePoint.ApplicationPages.DeleteWebPage.BtnDelete_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e)     at System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.OnClick(EventArgs e)     at System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.RaisePostBackEvent(String eventAr... 9b55c09e-f501-1059-492f-40de48580415
02/15/2019 14:00:29.35* w3wp.exe (SP13WEB2:0x068C)                  0x3660  SharePoint Foundation           General                         ai1wu   Medium  ...gument)     at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)     at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequest(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)     at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequest()     at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)     at System.Web.HttpApplication.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()     at System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStepImpl(IExecutionStep step)     at System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously)     at System.Web.HttpApplication.PipelineStepManager.ResumeSteps(Exception error)     at System.Web.HttpApplication.BeginProcessRequestNotification(HttpContext cont...  9b55c09e-f501-1059-492f-40de48580415
02/15/2019 14:00:29.35* w3wp.exe (SP13WEB2:0x068C)                  0x3660  SharePoint Foundation           General                         ai1wu   Medium  ...ext, AsyncCallback cb)     at System.Web.HttpRuntime.ProcessRequestNotificationPrivate(IIS7WorkerRequest wr, HttpContext context)     at System.Web.Hosting.PipelineRuntime.ProcessRequestNotificationHelper(IntPtr rootedObjectsPointer, IntPtr nativeRequestContext, IntPtr moduleData, Int32 flags)     at System.Web.Hosting.PipelineRuntime.ProcessRequestNotification(IntPtr rootedObjectsPointer, IntPtr nativeRequestContext, IntPtr moduleData, Int32 flags)     at System.Web.Hosting.UnsafeIISMethods.MgdIndicateCompletion(IntPtr pHandler, RequestNotificationStatus& notificationStatus)     at System.Web.Hosting.UnsafeIISMethods.MgdIndicateCompletion(IntPtr pHandler, RequestNotificationStatus& notificationStatus)     at System.Web.Hosting.PipelineRuntime.ProcessRequestNotificationHelper(IntPtr rooted...  9b55c09e-f501-1059-492f-40de48580415
02/15/2019 14:00:29.35* w3wp.exe (SP13WEB2:0x068C)                  0x3660  SharePoint Foundation           General                         ai1wu   Medium  ...ObjectsPointer, IntPtr nativeRequestContext, IntPtr moduleData, Int32 flags)     at System.Web.Hosting.PipelineRuntime.ProcessRequestNotification(IntPtr rootedObjectsPointer, IntPtr nativeRequestContext, IntPtr moduleData, Int32 flags)  9b55c09e-f501-1059-492f-40de48580415
02/15/2019 14:00:29.35  w3wp.exe (SP13WEB2:0x068C)                  0x3660  SharePoint Foundation           Micro Trace                     uls4    Medium  Micro Trace Tags: 0 nasq,6 agb9s,29 ak8dj,31 m7hw,219 b4ly,109 aix9j,0 ai1wu    9b55c09e-f501-1059-492f-40de48580415
02/15/2019 14:00:29.35  w3wp.exe (SP13WEB2:0x068C)                  0x3660  SharePoint Foundation           Monitoring                      b4ly    Medium  Leaving Monitored Scope (Request (POST:https://SITE/COLLECTION/TEST/_layouts/15/deleteweb.aspx)). Execution Time=400.505698959457   9b55c09e-f501-1059-492f-40de48580415
```

Answer (score 0):

With the risk of stating the obvious. Have you checked for any items/documents declared as records? That is separate from Information Policies.

Try using the code below to display the records. Code borrowed from [here](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/fromthefield/2015/11/04/finding-in-place-records-in-sharepoint-2010-and-sharepoint-2013-using-powershell/).

```
$webApp = Get-SPWebApplication http://content.contoso.com
$siteColl = $webApp.Sites
foreach ($site in $siteColl)
{
   $webs = $site.AllWebs
   foreach ($web in $webs)
   {
         $lists = $web.Lists
         foreach ($list in $lists)
         {
                if ($list.BaseTemplate -eq "DocumentLibrary")
                {
                       if (($list.Title -ne "List Template Gallery") -and ($list.Title -ne "Reporting Templates") -and ($list.Title -ne "Form Templates") -and ($list.Title -ne "Customized Reports") -and ($list.Title -ne "Site Assets") -and ($list.Title -ne "Style Library"))
                       {           
                             $auditQuery = New-Object -TypeName Microsoft.SharePoint.SPAuditQuery($site)   
                             $items = $list.get_Items()
                             foreach ($item in $items)
                             {
                                    $IsRecord = [Microsoft.Office.RecordsManagement.RecordsRepository.Records]::IsRecord($item)
                                    if ($IsRecord)
                                    {                                               $auditQuery.RestrictToListItem($item)
                                           $auditResults = $site.Audit.GetEntries($auditQuery)
                                           foreach ($entry in $auditResults)
                                           {
                                                 $userId = $entry.UserId           
                                                 $userEntry = $web.AllUsers | Where {$_.ID -eq $userId}
                                                 $userLogin = $userEntry.LoginName
                                           }
                                           $declaredDate = [Microsoft.Office.RecordsManagement.RecordsRepository.Records]::RecordDeclarationDate($item)
                                           Write-Host $declaredDate $item.Name $userLogin
                                    }
                             }
                       }
                }
         }
   }
   $site.Dispose()
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! Not at all too obvious as I don't have access to run PowerShell, so I've been stuck working on the front end. I'll send this to my counterpart in engineering and see if it gets us pointed in the right direction.

Comment: Hey Magus - Thanks again for your idea. Unfortunately we ran this and it returned no results. As I'm unaware of any records policies in place on any of the sites in this collection, that doesn't necessarily surprise me. Any other ideas?